# Wrong output when creating a lower diagonal triangle

Tags: c++

I am trying to create a program that takes lower diagonal values and than it stores in a 1-D array and then just print it .

Input:

1 0 0

2 3 0

4 5 6

expected output

1 0 0

2 3 0

4 5 6

current output

2 0 0

2 4 0

4 5 6

note I have given dimension to `3` already.

code:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
class matrix
{
    int size;
    int *a;

public:
    matrix(int size)                          //Matrix class
    {
        this->size = size;
        a = new int[(size * (size + 1) / 2)];           //creating 1-D array to store values
    }
    void set(int i, int j, int val)               //Function to set values in array "a".
    {
        if (i >= j)
            a[((i * (i - 1)) / 2) + (j - 1)] = val;
    }
    
    void display()                               //function to display values
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
            {
                if (i >= j)
                    cout << a[((i * (i - 1)) / 2) + (j - 1)] << " ";
                else
                    cout << "0 ";
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
    }
};
int main()
{
    int n = 3;                                   //dimension of matrix
    matrix a(n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)                //entering the values
    {
        int val;
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            cin >> val;
            a.set(i, j, val);
        }
    }
    a.display();

    return 0;
}
```

Attached compiler: https://onlinegdb.com/IrzmB04dB

Comment: Obviously `cout << a[((i * (i - 1)) / 2) + (j - 1)] << " ";` is wrong. You can see if you calculate for `i = 0` and `j = 0`. You can't access `a[-1]`. The array has `size * (size - 1) / 2` elements but the nested loop in `display` iterates `size * size` times.

Comment: @ThomasSablik Yeah it iterated size * size times but only for printing.

Comment: There are, IMHO, just too many errors in your code. The ways you calculate the size and indexes of your `a` array are completely wrong.

Comment: I could post a 'fixed' version of your program. But, as this is likely a homework problem, I don't think that would, ultimately, be helpful.

Comment: But think about it. If there are only `size * (size - 1) / 2` possible indexes but you are trying to access `size * size` different elements you have to go out of bounds or you have to access same elements multiple times.

Comment: And what will `(size - 1)/2` be when `size` is `3`? Clue: Less than 2.

Comment: @ThomasSablik But it will only try to print the values when ```i >= j```

Comment: Else it will print 0

Comment: Yes, you are right. I missed it.

Comment: And I am storing it in 1-D array like if I have size 5 than it will create size of array to 15 and than only store non zero elements.

Comment: No, if `size` is `5` you're storing `10` elements. `5 * (5 - 1) / 2 == 10`. If `size` is `3` you are storing `3` elements: `3 * (3 - 1) / 2 == 3`.

Comment: OK. So you've tried `size - 1` and now `size + 1`. Maybe strike a compromise?

Comment: Now you need a function to calculate the index. You're unit tests could be `f(0, 0) == 0`, `f(1, 0) == 1`, `f(1, 1) == 2`, `f(2, 0) == 3`, `f(2, 1) == 4`, `f(2, 2) == 5`, ...

Comment: You don't even need a unit test framework for small programs. You can use `assert` in the `main` function: https://wandbox.org/permlink/RO3QksvAt7m2N7cN

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your formula to find a matrix element `i,j` in a flattened array representation (that you call `a` in your code) of said matrix, `a[((i * (i - 1)) / 2) + (j - 1)]` is only correct in case indices `i,j` start counting from `1`, as in Fortran, and not from `0`, as in C++.

Also, the size of lower triangular matrix should include the main diagonal in your convention, so it should be `(size * (size - 1) / 2) + size` with the added `+ size` in the constructor.

Minding about this, your code becomes:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class matrix
{
    int size;
    int *a;

public:
    //Matrix class, ADD '+ size' TO a 
    matrix(int input_size): size(input_size), a(new int[size * (size + 1) / 2] + size) {}    

    void set(int i, int j, int val)               //Function to set values in array "a".
    {
        if (i >= j) {
            //i++; j++;                            // !!HERE!! START i,j AT 1
            //a[((i * (i - 1)) / 2) + (j - 1)] = val;
            // OR, EQUIVALENTLY
            a[((i * (i + 1)) / 2) + j] = val;
        }
    }

    void display()                               //function to display values
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= size; i++)        // START i AT 1
        {
            for (int j = 1; j <= size; j++)    // START j AT 1
            {
                if (i >= j)
                    cout << a[((i * (i - 1)) / 2) + (j - 1)] << " ";
                else
                    cout << "0 ";
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
    }
};


int main()
{
    int n = 3;                                   //dimension of matrix
    matrix a(n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)                //entering the values
    {
        int val;
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            cin >> val;
            a.set(i, j, val);
        }
    }
    a.display();

    return 0;
}
```

Resulting output:

```
1
0
0
2
3
0
4
5
6
1 0 0
2 3 0
4 5 6
```

Comment: You are right, it would read better. Also `this->size` in the constructor does not flow too well. Could have called the input parameter some other way, say `input_size`, and set `size = input_size`.

Comment: Yes, in the initialiser list. I will update my answer.

Comment: As a last step you could replace the 1-based loops with 0-based loops and `cout << a[((i * (i - 1)) / 2) + (j - 1)] << " ";` with `cout << a[i * (i + 1) / 2 + j] << " ";`

Comment: I want to leave the `i,j = 1` correction evident, so it is easier for the OP to see what to modify and also so that the code is more in tune with the text of my answer. It is difficult to convey the idea that it is all a matter of starting values in `display()`, if I change the formula. Inside the `set()` function, on the other hand, it was easier to present both approaches.